# Powershell script on mac error

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

Just downloaded powershell trying to run a script on Mac and received the following error. Would appreciate any help from anyone familiar for a non-windows user. :)

[image]

Comment: You do not say what you are doing.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the Meltdown/Spectre dectection script. That script only works for Windows systems. As you can tell from the error as well, it's trying to load "ntdll.dll", which is not a thing on Mac.

Comment: Would wine on mac be able to run this as an application?

Comment: Nasir is on point, here. As for wine, that would be a no, as this tool is looking for the Windows Registry settings and Windows user-mode dlls. Even folks running this on Windows boxes are have a few issues due to the Anti-Virus they have on their systems which may not be compatible and the version of Windows they are running.

Answer (score 1):

The script you are running is not compatible with MacOS. It is trying to pull in resources that are only on Windows.

For Information on the Meltdown/Spectre vulnerability on MacOS, see Apples post: [About speculative execution vulnerabilities in ARM-based and Intel CPUs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208394)

Answer (score 0):

The Step by Step instructions are here:

> Supports Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 17.04, Debian 8, Debian 9, CentOS 7, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7, OpenSUSE 42.2, Fedora 25, Fedora 26, Arch Linux, and macOS 10.12.
>
> For Linux distributions that are not officially supported, you can try using the PowerShell AppImage. You can also try deploying PowerShell binaries directly using the Linux tar.gz archive, but you would need to set up the necessary dependencies based on the OS in separate steps.
>
> All packages are available on our GitHub releases page. Once the package is installed, run pwsh from a terminal.
>
> https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md#macos-1011

Is this and new install and was install successful?
How or what commands did you run to install it, meaning following the defined steps.

You do not say what you are doing that caused this error and or is this a script you wrote or downloaded and are trying to use.

Point of note PoSH Core does not have all the features of Windows PowerShell, at least not yet. So, you have to work in those confines.

If this is from the install, you'll have to remove and reinstall.